# How do I change the placeholder text?

Tags: react-dropdown-tree-select

Adding the following prop does not seem to work

text={{placeholder: "Select product"}}

```
<DropdownTreeSelect
      data={data}
      texts={{placeholder: 'Some other text'}}
      onChange={onChange}
      className="bootstrap-demo"
    />
```

Placeholder text still shoews default "Choose ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prop name is `placeholderText` try:

```
<DropdownTreeSelect
      data={data}
      placeholderText={'Some other text'}
      onChange={onChange}
      className="bootstrap-demo"
    />
```

Comment: Is there additional documentation somewhere else? The  documentation on github does not have this.

Comment: Yeah, that's odd. Looks like the documentation on [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropdown-tree-select) is different.

Comment: It looks like the master branch is different from the develop branch.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with texts={{ placeholder: "Search" }} and it works like a champ!